# There are $n^{n-3}$ numbers of trees with named edges - how to proof?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

How to proof that there are

$$ n^{n-3} $$

trees with $n$ (unnamed) vertexes and $n-1$ named edges: $\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n-1\right\}$?

Comment: There is a well-known result in graph theory that there are $n^{n-2}$ vertex-labeled tress with $n$ vertices. Can you come up with an $n$-to-$1$ correspondence between the vertex-labeled trees and the edge-labeled trees? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula)

Comment: But why is it mentioned that there are $n$ vertices ? is this information important?

Comment: @Kuifje - Yes, there is this information in task. But I think is obvious: every tree with n-1 edges has n vertexes

Comment: Thanks. I think the question is not well posed. If my understanding is correct, I would say: "Given a graph with $n$ vertices, how many trees are there with $n-1$ labelled edges ?"

Answer (score 1):

HINT: There are $n$ ways to pick one vertex to be the root of the tree. Once you’ve done that, you can define a direction on each edge by considering its relationship to the root. Then use that directions of the edges together with their label to label the vertices other than the root. Then apply [Cayley’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_formula).

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of a result from Cayley, known as…[Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula).

Comment: No, it isn’t. Cayley’s formula counts vertex-labelled trees.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Would it be possible to work with the line graph? I was thinking that a line graph of a graph with $n-1$ labelled edges is a graph with $n-1$ labelled vertices. Therefore by Cayley, there are $n^{n-3}$ trees on this line graph. But I am not sure where to go after that…this may be a bad idea.

Comment: The line graph won’t in general be a tree.

Comment: You mean the inverse of a line graph that is a tree isn't a tree in general?

Comment: I mean that the line graph of a tree is not in general a tree. The line graph of the tree $K_{1,3}$, for instance, is $K_3$.